# Java Priority Queue of Pairs: how to insert pairs sorted by both elements

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am brand new to Java, and need to write a program that takes in data from a .txt file and adds it to a collection that automatically sorts it so that it can be easily printed in a logical format.

This is an assignment for a class, and it was specified that we need to choose a collection that automatically sorts the data as it is added. We're not able to use any sort of Collections.sort() method, and we can only iterate through the collection once when printing the final output.

The data on each line of the .txt file is in the following format:
String person, String locationName\n

The final goal for the output of this program, once the data is added to the collection and the collection is printed, is to list the locations in alphabetical order, and beneath each location, to list the people who have been to that location in alphabetical order, alongside the number of times they have been to that location.

The best way I could come up with to do this would be to make a priority queue of pairs, and I want to know if it is possible to write a Comparator that sorts the data by both of the String elements, in exactly this format, and if so what the syntax would look like.

To give you an example:

data.txt:

```
Andrew, Beta
Bob, Alpha
Bob, Alpha
Andrew, Alpha
```

pairs once sorted by both elements:

```
Andrew, Alpha
Bob, Alpha
Bob, Alpha
Andrew, Beta
```

expected.txt: (format in which it should be easy to print once this is accomplished)

```
Alpha:
   Andrew   1
   Bob      2
Beta:
   Andrew   1
```

Comment: Why priority queue? Read everything into a list, then sort the list. If you have a custom class for your pair, you can make it Comparable and don't even need a separate Comparator.

Comment: It's an assignment and one of the specifications is that we have to use a collection that automatically sorts the data as it is added. we can't use any kind of collections.sort() method. Sorry, I should have said. I'll add it to the post

Comment: Then you have the `TreeSet`. Unless you need to support duplicates.

Comment: Either way you need a custom comparator but you should note that PriorityQueue only sorts the first element.

Comment: @PeterLawrey But you can pull elements out of it in total order.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, but you can't just iterate it. You have to remove all the elements to get the order.

Comment: You can provide a `Comparator`, or implement `Comparable`, in such a way as to sort on as many attributes as you like.

Comment: If you create a class that has `Name` and `Location` properties and store those in the priority queue, the comparator becomes somewhat easier to write. That also more clearly models the problem.

Comment: I was thinking of making a Pair class that would do that. There are lots of duplicates here, because in some instances the same person has visited the same place upwards of 30 times (the data.txt file is really large). That's why I thought I couldn't use a set. I just don't know how to have both elements in class Pair, if I do it that way (name, location), automatically alphabetically sorted, because like I said, I'm not to use any .sort() methods and can only interate through the collection one time when printing